# What font qualities should be used in sales/specials promotions?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

I'm struggling to research and find some literature regarding guidelines when it comes to using fonts that would be used inside sales pamphlets or on a website/email.

Whenever I search I get fonts that are on sale or on promotion. Are there particular font qualities that are used in sales advertising (pamphlets, newletters etc)? If you have any specific font suggestions those are certainly welcome as well.

Comment: To add to the already great answers, look around on design websites like Behance and Dribbble and spot trends. See what other people do and what works for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one "right" font in advertising materials, though there are some general guidelines for making media more readable.

**Print:** Use ornamental fonts for big titles only, sans serif fonts for headers and captions, and serif fonts for large bodies of text (ie a paragraph description). Serif fonts are good for this purpose because the little "tails," or serifs on the letters better help our eyes to connect the word. Body text shouldn't be smaller than 10pt to be sure it is readable.

**Screen:** Sans serif fonts. Try to stick with fonts that are system fonts, such as Arial, for online newsletters/websites/etc. This makes it easier to ensure that the font won't be distorted or misinterpreted across different systems. Text read on screen should generally be larger (min 12-16px).

**Some robust serif fonts:** Garamond, Times, Sabon, Minion, Baskerville
**Some good sans serif fonts:** Arial, Helvetica, Futura, Gill Sans, Myriad, Univers, Franklin Gothic

The above are basic fonts, but well developed and versatile. There are many more.

Comment: Arial is arguably not a great screen typeface. There are typically better options than Arial for websites.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there particular font qualities that are used in sales advertising

No.

There are particular font qualities that are often used to sell particular products and services, however. But that doesn't mean you have to use the same ones.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the product and audience.

If you're advertising a security company, you would use a strong, bold, no-nonsense font.

For lingerie, you'd use a feminine, elegant font.

In other words, research and find a font whose look and feel matches the message.